# Create opposite column with clause UPDATE pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

That helped me to my first question

```
set serveroutput on;
begin 
FOR v IN REVERSE 1..5 
LOOP
  dbms_output.put_line(v);
end loop;
END;
```

Second question

I have two column in my table
in first column i have numbers from 1...to 10000. by order ASC
Second column is empty and i need use an update statement to tacke numbers 
from first column but in reverse(in opposite way). in SQL method and PL/SQL.
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a couple of ways of doing it - one involving pl/sql and one pure sql:

```
DECLARE
  v_max_num NUMBER := 5;
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1..v_max_num
  LOOP
    INSERT INTO your_table (num_asc, num_desc)
    VALUES (i, v_max_num + 1 - i);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

This takes the max number, adds one to it (since max_number - max_number = 0, and we would want the row with the num_asc = max_number to have a num_desc = 1) and then subtracts the current number of the loop.

```
INSERT INTO your_table (num_asc, num_desc)
SELECT LEVEL num_asc, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY LEVEL DESC) num_desc
FROM   dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5;
```

This one uses a connect-by "trick" to produce a list of numbers, and then uses the row_number() analytic function to number the rows in descending order.

---

If you're saying that the PL/SQL code is not working, I suggest you replace the insert with a dbms_output.put_line statement that outputs both values.

For example, taking the max number as 100, as per your example in the comments, doing:

```
DECLARE
  v_max_num NUMBER := 100;
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1..v_max_num
  LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line('num_asc = '||i||', num_desc = '||(v_max_num + 1 - i));
  END LOOP;
END; 
/
```

I get an output of:

```
num_asc = 1, num_desc = 100
num_asc = 2, num_desc = 99
num_asc = 3, num_desc = 98
num_asc = 4, num_desc = 97
num_asc = 5, num_desc = 96
num_asc = 6, num_desc = 95
num_asc = 7, num_desc = 94
num_asc = 8, num_desc = 93
num_asc = 9, num_desc = 92
num_asc = 10, num_desc = 91
<snip>
num_asc = 91, num_desc = 10
num_asc = 92, num_desc = 9
num_asc = 93, num_desc = 8
num_asc = 94, num_desc = 7
num_asc = 95, num_desc = 6
num_asc = 96, num_desc = 5
num_asc = 97, num_desc = 4
num_asc = 98, num_desc = 3
num_asc = 99, num_desc = 2
num_asc = 100, num_desc = 1
```

So the loop is working as expected. The issue must therefore lie either with the insert (in which case, you'd get an error) or with the fact that you're querying the table in a different session to that which the PL/SQL ran in. To test the latter, I would add a commit into the anonymous PL/SQL block just after the end loop.

Comment: in pl/sql your code to me with my replacing ofc some datatypes not inserting into table any data.

Comment: this my code pl/sql DECLARE
  v_max_num NUMBER := 100;
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1..v_max_num
  LOOP
    INSERT INTO test_tabs (acc_val,desc_ord)
    VALUES (i, v_max_num + 1 - i);
  END LOOP;
END;

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a couple of things you could try, if your PL/SQL version is still not working.

Comment: Bonneist how can i use only update clause(SQL, PL/SQL) by taking all info from 1 column to second with reverse ?

Comment: You should ask that as a separate question. Remember to provide as much information as possible (as text, not images) about your input data and your expected output in your new question.

Answer (score 3):

Hope this answers your question.

```
set serveroutput on;
begin 
FOR v IN REVERSE 1..5 
LOOP
  dbms_output.put_line(v);
end loop;
END;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. But there one more thing when i putting from 1..5 to one column, and 5..1 to second column only one column displaying with numbers which was last ( compiled )

Comment: Do you mean you want 1.5 in one column  and 5..1 in another column in one go?

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN    
FOR v IN REVERSE 1..5
    LOOP
       insert into test_tabs(desc_ord)
           values(v);
    END LOOP;
END;
```

try this out

Comment: thanks a lot but when im changing column name to insert opposite numbers the first one is erasing and remains only one column with numbers

Comment: your question is not clear can you please explain it little more